# ComboBox value undefined

Tags: extjs, drop-down-menu, combobox

I have a program with 2 DropDownBoxes, where 1 of the drop box value is depanded on the value of the first (users value).

My problem is that I try to get that value from one drop box and I get "cant get value of undefined".

This is the code:

```
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    displayField: 'vendor_name',
    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'Choose vendor...',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    fieldLabel: 'Vendor Name',
    margin: 10,
    id: 'txtBidVendor',
    labelWidth: 100,
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'vendor_name'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            timeout: 120000,
            url: 'GetVendors.jsp',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                successProperty: 'success'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    })
},
{
    xtype: 'combobox',
    displayField: 'rate_desc',
    typeAhead: true,
    mode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    emptyText: 'Choose Quality...',
    selectOnFocus: true,
    fieldLabel: 'Vendor Quality',
    margin: 10,
    id: 'txtBidVendorQuality',
    labelWidth: 100,
    store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'rate_desc'}
        ],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            timeout: 120000,
            url: 'GetVendorQuality.jsp?' + Ext.urlEncode({'bid_vendor': Ext.getCmp('txtBidVendor').value}), 
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'data',
                successProperty: 'success'
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    })
},
```

I get the error in the line where I try getting `Ext.getCmp('txtBidVendor').value`

Comment: Is there an instance of `txtBidVendor`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to mention the `valueField` for the combo. This will fetch the value for that `combobox`.

`displayField` is only used to mention what will be displayed. `valueField`  keeps the real value which will be accessed by  `Ext.getCmp('txtBidVendor').value`

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you won't get it.

You have to set this second url in the select event listener of first combo.

Because here before combo is created you are trying to access the value set in combo.
If you have any default value atleast set the 2nd combo url after load of first combo.